# mirror from xubuntu 16.04 to roku 3?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu

is there anyway I could mirror the screen of my xubuntu 16.04 laptop to roku 3? how to add roku to my laptop, like one could under windows. is there any specific software I have to install? thank you.